# Trying to find the average of element[0] in multiple rows

Tags: python

Hi I am trying to sum together all of the first elements in a whole bunch of lists so for example I have
[20, Private, 266015, Some-college, 10, Never-married, Sales, Own-child, Black, Male, 0, 0, 44, United-States, <=50K] (age being the first element in this case 20) I need to find the average age of a person who earns <=50K there are over 30,000 records like this one how can I add each age with the one in the next record? This is the code I have I am getting something but it is not right. Any help would be great thanks.

```
    for row in f:
        row = row.split(", ")
        try:
            row[0] = int(row[0])
            row[2] = None
            row[3] = None
            row[4] = int(row[4])
            row[10] = int(row[10])
            row[11] = int(row[11])
            row[12] = int(row[12])
            row[13] = None

            if "?" in row:
                continue
            if row[-1] == ">50K":
                total_count +=1
                age_over_count = row[0]+row[0]
                average_age_over = age_over_count/total_count
```

Comment: use `zip` function : `zip(*list_of_records)[0]` will gave you a list of first elements .

Comment: If you're trying to find the average of the first column in this data you need to divide by the `total_count` after you have finished summing all the ages (i.e unindent the `average_age_over = age_over_count/total_count` line to be outside of the `for` loop)

Comment: Do you have to implement this yourself for an assignment or a course?  If not, it'll be much faster to work with this dataset using [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org) or a similar library.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the average of `row[0]` given `row[-1]== ">50k"` you need to calculate the average after the loop is finished and then also keep adding to your age_over_count with the value you already have, i.e. with +=...

```
for row in f:
    row = row.split(", ")
    try:
        row[0] = int(row[0])
        row[2] = None
        row[3] = None
        row[4] = int(row[4])
        row[10] = int(row[10])
        row[11] = int(row[11])
        row[12] = int(row[12])
        row[13] = None

        if "?" in row:
            continue
        if row[-1] == ">50K":
            total_count +=1
            age_over_count += row[0]          # <- Keeps adding what you have.
average_age_over = age_over_count/total_count # <- Calculates average.
```